# Listing foreign key object field in HttpResponse results

Tags: python, django

I apologize ahead of time, as I'm sure this question has been answered in full, but I must be missing a key component.

I'm attempting to list a report's created_by user's first_name field in the existing results.  From what I can tell, I have everything set up correctly, but only the Report object's attributes are rendering.

In **models.py**, I have an object "Report" with an FK to the "User" object:

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='users', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In **views.py**, I am creating the "reports" object using this:

```
reports = Report.objects.order_by('-created_on').select_related('created_by').all()
```

Running this in a django shell shows the SQL that I would expect, including the first_name field being pulled from auth_user.first_name:

```
>>> print(Report.objects.order_by('-created_on').select_related('created_by').all().query)
SELECT "report"."id", "report"."name", "report"."created_on", "report"."created_by_id", "report"."data_source", "report"."report_date", "report"."case_id", "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "report" INNER JOIN "auth_user" ON ("report"."created_by_id" = "auth_user"."id") ORDER BY "report"."created_on" DESC
```

However, I must be doing something wrong in my HTML:

```
{% for report in reports %}
<tr>
<td>{{ report.name }}</td>
<td>{{ report.users.first_name }}</td>
<td>{{ report.report_date }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I've attempted just about every variation of report.*.first_name that I can think of, but in each case, only the report.name and report.report_date values are coming through.  I must be missing something because even though when I'm printing the SQL via the django shell it shows the auth_user fields, if I simply ask for the .values() from that command, then only the report fields are returned.

Comment: Why do you need `select_related('created_by')` when you can just normal output the foreign key value in the template like `{{ report.created_by.first_name }}` ? also your foreign key in the Report model name is created_by and not users

Comment: You're absolutely right.  Thank you for pointing that out.  This resolved the issue.